# Algorithm: How to disperse smaller spheres into a direction within a large sphere

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

I am trying to write a C source code visualization program which I expect to draw out function hierarchy using spheres inside spheres.

For a simple example, in code like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int pow(int base, int power) {
    while(--power) {
        base*=base;
    }
    return base;
}

int checkOdd(int i) {
    if (i%2==0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int checkPrime(int i) {
    int j = i;
    if (!checkOdd(i)) {
        return 0;
    }
    for(j=1; j<i/2; j++) {
        if (i%j==0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 2;
    int res = pow(a,b);
    int bl = checkPrime(res);
    printf("%d",res);
    return 1;
}
```

The largest sphere which is the main function has two functions inside it, pow and checkPrime, which are two spheres inside main's sphere. Checkprime function's sphere has checkOdd's sphere in it.

I would like it so that the children spheres are somewhat clumped together in one side of the larger sphere, because I would like some space left out for putting in other things. However, the spheres must not touch each other, and the radius of the spheres are pre-determined and can not change to accomodate drawing accurately. I need an algorithm which determines the perfect center coordinates which would allow the smaller spheres not to touch each other while still being collected to one side of the larger sphere.

I have a 3D vector which shows the direction at which the smaller spheres must be concentrated in, looking from the center of the larger sphere. In the case of the picture, my 3D vector is facing bottom-down in a 2D-sense looking at the screen.

Currently my algorithm produces this by dispersing the sphere's center around a circle projected onto the larger sphere's surface, but it fails as the spheres overlap. Can anyone enlighten me with a way to disperse smaller spheres to one direction within the larger sphere?

[image: trial]

I am using OpenGL and I prepared a function which can draw those transparent mesh spheres by feeding center coordinate and radius. I have knowledge of parent sphere's center and radius in designing this algorithm.

Comment: What does "somewhat all located in the same direction looking from a point in the larger sphere" mean to you?

Comment: Instead of inner spheres being dispersed evenly, they are clumped towards a specific direction. The image shows me trying to space out the spheres in bottom-right direction looking from the point where "int main" is written.

Comment: this looks like bin packing problem .... I do not think your approach will work because with more complex programs you will start have problems with space anyway.... instead try do this backwards 1.  start with no recursions for now (no sphere in sphere...except the main of coarse) 2. create a list of all spheres inside owners sphere with their relative radius. 3. try to fit them into smallest space possible 4. find the bounding sphere 5. rescale all to match the bound sphere desired radius 6. handle recursions recursively ...  This is far from solution but I would start this way.

Comment: How can I come up with the coordinates of the center of the children spheres so that they are evenly spaced out within a confined area of the parent sphere? Any mathematical approaches to this?

Comment: If you only have a vague idea of what you mean by "in this region" then you can't expect to use something very precise. It would be a bad idea to require an algorithm to be able to solve very hard packing problems. Instead, you might be a little flexible with the sizes of the spheres, and use a physics engine to make the spheres attracted by a point in the region and repelled by each other. This would be a hill-climbing approach, so you might get different results from different starting points.

Comment: The direction I want the children spheres to face within the parent sphere is going to be dependent on how much instructions there are within the functions representing each sphere. This direction will be represented by a 3d vector, and I will have to think through how I am going to come up with the values of the vector. But I am going to be feeding this vector to the function that draws the children spheres, so the drawing function will know numerically where the children spheres will be scattered. I am not sure if I understood your comment accurately but does this help?